# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, html5, laravel, laravel-5

este es mi primer post y espero me ayuden y poderlos y ayudar a muchos de vosotros de igual manera. Como vieron en el titulo me genera ese error, y eso me pasa ahora que estoy aprendiendo Laravel 5.1

Este es el error

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_laravel\resources\views\pelicula\create.blade.php)

Mis codigos son los siguientes.

**MovieController**

```
<?php

namespace cinema\Http\Controllers;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use cinema\Http\Requests;
use cinema\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use cinema\Genre;
use cinema\Movie;

class MovieController extends Controller{

public function index(){
    //
}



public function create(){
    $genres = Genre::lists('genre','id');
    return view('pelicula.create',compact('genres'));
}

public function store(Request $request){
    Movie::create($request->all());
    return "Listo";
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.admin')

@section('content')
@include('alertas.ErroresFormulario')

{!!Form::open(['route'=>'pelicula.store', 'method'=>'POST','files'=>  true])!!}
    @include('pelicula.forms.crearPelicula')
    {!!Form::submit(['Registrar','class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}

@endsection
```

Este es mi 
**crearPelicula.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('nombre','Nombre:')!!}
{!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese  Nombre de la pelicula'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('elenco','Elenco:')!!}
{!!Form::text('cast',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese   el elenco'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('direccion','Dirección:')!!}
{!!Form::text('direction',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingrese el Director'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('duracion','Duración:')!!}
{!!Form::text('duration',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Duración de la pelicula'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('Poster','Poster:')!!}
{!!Form::file('path')!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('Genero','Genero:')!!}
{!!Form::select('genre_id',$genres)!!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás pasando un array como primer parámetro en el submit del formulario, cuando debería ser un string:

```
{!! Form::submit('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

El segundo parámetro es el array de opciones.

---

Dejo como referencia el código de LaravelCollective que hace referencia al botón submit:

```
/**
 * Create a submit button element.
 *
 * @param  string $value
 * @param  array  $options
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function submit($value = null, $options = [])
{
    return $this->input('submit', null, $value, $options);
}
```

Comment: Soluciono el error, muchas gracias. Pero de ese me salto a otro jajajaja pero este me estaba sacando unas cuantas canas :c